# Where is the profile picture stored on OSX?

Tags: macos

I would like to know where the profile picture is stored on OSX that is created when you setup the account first.

Comment: Hi, I made your question more generic as Yosemite questions will more often than not get deleted. And the answer you are looking for is most likely in the question I linked above. Just tested on Mavericks. I doubt Yosemite will be different.

Comment: I tired the approach mentioned earlier but got some error related to dscl. the following worked

dscl . -read /Users/<Short Name> JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > /Users/<Short Name>/Desktop/Profile-Image.jpg

Comment: Isn't that the same command from the question I linked above?